# Pip install mediapipe showing error even after installing 64 bit version

Tags: python, mediapipe

I tried to install mediapipe in Windows using Python 3.11 64 bit version for a mini hand detection project.

But it showed me the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
```

Answer (score 0):

According to official docs (https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/install.html#installing-on-windows)

> Running MediaPipe on Windows is experimental.

Maybe you could give it try using WSL.

Answer (score 0):

I just found it useful to downgrade Python to 3.9.x